# How to add prefix string in jqgrid column using date formatter

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am formatting the jqgrid column using  -
**formatoptions: { srcformat: 'ISO8601Long', newformat: 'H:i' }, formatter: 'date'**

I want to add a prefix string in **Stopped at** before the time.

Please help...
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) which calls original date formatter and prepend the requested string before:

```
formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "H:i" },
formatter: function (value, options) {
    return "Stopped at " + $.fn.fmatter.call(this, "date", value, options);
}
```